# Looking for an 80s Korean or Japanese movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, cyberpunk

The cover is a girl riding a motorcycle with a guy on it and it is like a perspective thing. It had a blueish-green filter on top.

I think it might have been a sci-fi, cyberpunk movie. I remember it being described as like an Asian *Blade Runner*-type movie. it was made late 80s or late 90s I think. I haven't watched it, just seen the cover.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the provided answer indicates that there are no Fantasy or Sci-Fi aspects.

Answer (score 1):

I just found it. I searched up what I said and it popped up. It's [Fallen Angels](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112913/).

> Wong Chi-ming, a cold-blooded Hong-Kong-based assassin, has decided that he wants out. One last job stands in the way of a new life; however, Wong is unaware that his female partner-in-crime is utterly infatuated with him. Then, Wong has a late-night encounter with seductive Blondie in a fast-food restaurant, only to spark his obsessed partner's jealousy. Elsewhere in the city, mute Ho Chi-mo, who has recently escaped from prison, uses unorthodox ways to eke out an existence. During one of his nightly escapades, Ho crosses paths with Charlie, who enlists his help to find her ex-boyfriend's new lover. But, can there be redemption for the fallen angels?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You should [edit] your answer to include a plot summary or at least a link to information about the movie

Comment: Also, you will be able to accept your self-answer by clicking on the checkmark in about 44 hours.